# virsh vcpu_period and vcpu_quota

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cpu-usage, vcpu, virsh

I have been looking into ways to divide my CPU amongst KVM guests other than by just setting vCPU access limits. I understand the concept of cpu_shares which can be set/displayed with `virsh schedinfo`, but I also found `vcpu_period` and `vcpu_quota` listed with this command as shown below:

[image]

Looking at [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh), I know what the acceptable input values are but could somebody please explain in simple terms what these two parameters actually do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> quota
>   The optional quota element specifies the maximum allowed bandwidth(unit: microseconds). A domain with quota as any negative value indicates that the domain has infinite bandwidth, which means that it is not bandwidth controlled. The value should be in range [1000, 18446744073709551] or less than 0. A quota with value 0 means no value. You can use this feature to ensure that all vcpus run at the same speed. Only QEMU driver support since 0.9.4, LXC since 0.9.10

http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsCPUTuning

Comment: Brilliant! So pleased someone finally got back to me, even if it is 2.5 years later.